# NSUserDefaults flushes data before I retrieve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am using NSUserDefaults for saving NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionery as

```
NSUserDefaults *nsdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSMutableDictionary *appDetail = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[sbjasonObj objectWithString:result]];

    if ([appDetail objectForKey:KStores]) {
        NSArray *stores = [appDetail objectForKey:KStores];
        NSLog(@"%@",stores);
        [nsdefaults setObject:stores forKey:KStores];
    }

    NSString *colorString = [appDetail objectForKey:KColorTheme];

    [nsdefaults setObject:colorString forKey:KColorTheme];

    NSString *lookBookURL = [appDetail objectForKey:kLookBook];
    NSLog(@"look_book%@",lookBookURL);

    [nsdefaults setObject:lookBookURL forKey:kLookBook];

    [nsdefaults setObject:appDetail forKey:kGetAppDetail];//using same key to save in sandbox
    [nsdefaults synchronize];
    [appDetail release];
```

and retrieving this data as

```
shopsLocations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                     objectForKey:KStores]];
    NSLog(@"shopsLocations: %@",shopsLocations);
```

It gives me "shopsLocations: (
)" means 0 value. Also when I try to retrieve "appDetail", It also gives zero keys and values.

My question is 
1. Can I save array and dictionary in NSUserDefaults?
2. When data in NSUserDefaults is flushed out?
3. How to retrieve data from NSUserDefaults?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing the appdetail and change it to nsdefaults

Comment: where should i remove appdetail??

Comment: I am getting stores via nslog before setting but unable to retrieve.

Comment: try this [nsdefaults setObject:appdetail forKey:Kstores]; at the top of the first if statement

Comment: issue is in retrieving data and one more thing i am setting these values very often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is the content of your `stores` array?

If you want to save to NSUserDefaults (with `setObject:forKey:`) the only allowed content are objects that can be transformed into a property list. These objects are `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate` and `NSNumber` (int, float, bool).

If you want to save something else to `NSUserDefaults` you have to create a NSData object first. You can do this with the help of [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can save array and dictionary in NSUserDefaults.

`arrayForKey` and `dictionaryForKey` are getters. Use setObject to set an array.

To not flush your data in NSUserDefaults use,

```
[nsdefaults setObject:colorString forKey:KColorTheme];
[nsdefaults synchronize];
```

**Updated :**

To retrieve,

```
shopsLocations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:KColorTheme]];
```

Comment: I am doing the same as you said. See and read question again.

Comment: To retrieve array stored in NSUserDefaults, you are using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:KStores]` instead use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:KStores]`

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
if ([appDetail objectForKey:KStores]) {
        NSArray *stores = [appDetail objectForKey:KStores];
        NSLog(@"%@",stores);
        [nsdefaults setObject:stores forKey:KStores];
    }
```

with

```
if ([appDetail objectForKey:KStores]) {
        NSArray *stores=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[appDetail objectForKey:KStores]];
        NSLog(@"%@",stores);
        [nsdefaults setObject:stores forKey:KStores];
        [stores release];
    }
```

and let me know if it works.

Comment: those bugs are fixed. I'll remove my previous comments.

Comment: No, that code wasn't okay. ^^ It had a leak and more importantly you released an autoreleased object which would have lead to a crash.

Comment: OK thanks.. just when I start thinking that you are through with memory management something new comes up.. but thanks anyway... Don't know how long will it take learn this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly store an Array in NSUserDefaults. Instead, archive your array to a structure like NSData and then store that in NSUserDefaults.

E.g.

```
if ([appDetail objectForKey:KStores]) {
    NSArray *stores = [appDetail objectForKey:KStores];
    NSLog(@"%@",stores);
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:stores];
    [nsdefaults setObject:data forKey:KStores];
}
```

To retrieve the array, do the reverse. I.e. Retrieve the NSData and then unarchive it to an array

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:KStores];
shopsLocations = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```